# why am i getting segmentation fault in this code

Tags: c++, vector

This is a simple code which doesn't works for me.
can i not save a vector's elements in a loop like Matlab. i also
need x to grow in size later.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nxr,i;
    double dxr,ll;

    nxr = 2400;
    lr = 0.6;
    dxr = lr/nxr;
    std::vector<double> x;

    for (i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        x[i]=(i+1)*dxr;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of bound access here:

```
x[i]=(i+1)*dxr;
```

Your vector has size 0. Either call `push_back` or initialize it to the right size:

```
x.push_back((i+1)*dxr);
```

or

```
std::vector<double> x(6);
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<double> x;` creates an empty vector, you have to use `push_back` to add elements or pre-allocate the elements - `std::vector<double> x(6);`, then use `operator []`.